# What are differences between restarting apache2 and service apache2?

Tags: 13.04, apache2, services

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

What are the differences?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service` calls scripts located in `/etc/init.d`, so there are no differences in the result in this case.

From the `man service`:

```
service runs a System V init script or upstart job in as predictable environment as possible, removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /.

The  SCRIPT  parameter  specifies  a  System  V init script, located in /etc/init.d/SCRIPT, or the name of an upstart job in /etc/init.
```